# ExchangeService.cs Not Found

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have the following code which was working yesterday but isn't anymore and I can't figure out why.

Visual Studio keeps telling me that ExchangeService.cs can't be found, however I have installed the EWS package via nuget.

It also appears to be looking for the missing file at \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService service = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The EWS package just adds a dll.  Why is the error saying it can't find the source file?

Comment: Is it having a problem building or running?

Comment: Code Builds but when I try and run it VS opens a page saying source not found ExchangeService.cs

Comment: Its my VS setup, tried same code elsewhere and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but I had the same issue so I'm posting my fix, hopefully it'll help someone.

This was happening to me, the application would run fine, but in debug mode if a line tried to call any EWS API class the open file dialog box was displayed, clicking cancel returns errors such as:

ExtendedProperties.cs not found

ExchangeService.cs not found

CalendarFolder.cs not found

I eventually found the fix:

1. uninstall EWS Managed API
2. re-install EWS Managed API
3. Open Visual STudio and remove the EWS references from the project (everything under Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices)
4. then re-add the EWS references